# How to validate mobile number for countries in angular?

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

Here I validate mobile number using below code for universally for all countries using below code using this regex (`/^(\+\d{1,3}[- ]?)?\d{10}$/`) I doing but it not accept this type numbers (`(+91)9876543210` OR `09876543210`)

This type of mobile Numbers accept

```
+91 9876543210 (or all other country code)

(+91) 9876543210

(+91)9876543210

+919876543210

+91-9876543210

(+91)-9876543210

9876543210

09876543210
```

not accept numbers like

```
++91 9876543210(double ++),

+91  9876543210(double spaces),

+91 987 65   7 4 688(not more than one space),

+91 808-75-74-678(not more than one -),

+91-846363,

80873(number less than 10 digit),

8087339090456(number greater than 10 digit),

0000000000(all zeros),

+91 0000000(all zeros with country code)
```

HTML

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Enter contact No." [(ngModel)]="userObj.contactno" name="contactNo" required>
</mat-form-field>
<button mat-button color="primary" (click)="saveNewCustomerDetails()">SAVE</button>
```

TS

```
   saveNewCustomerDetails(){
     if(this.userObj.contactno.match(/^(\+\d{1,3}[- ]?)?\d{10}$/)){
        console.log("valid mobile number");
     }else{
        console.log("Invalid mobile number");
     }
   }
```

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288535/angular-international-phone-number-with-country-code-and-flag

Comment: I see no exact reason to reject these numbers like *more than one -* and *all zeros*, besides that you can always get invalid number even if it's pattern looks alright.

Comment: and you can always combine individual pattern use or (`|`) operator

Comment: I suggest scrubbing the numbers to remove whitespace, then doing the comparison.  Note that each country code has its own accepted set of numbers, so your problem quickly becomes a can of worms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to incorporate literal parenthesis in your regex which can be there optionally and since they have special meaning hence you need to escape them in your regex.

Seeing your last mobile number `09876543210`, it seems you optionally want to support zero before a number if there is no country code, so you can have zero in alternation for your country code part.

And last, like you don't want to support a number only having all zeroes, you can have a negative look ahead `(?!0+$)` in your regex. Your updated regex becomes,

```
^(?!0+$)(?:\(?\+\d{1,3}\)?[- ]?|0)?\d{10}$
```

**[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/E9SCcu/1)**

Also, you if you don't want to support numbers having only same digits like `2222222222` or `5555555555` then your negative look ahead needs to be written as `(?!(\d)\1+$)` and your regex will become,

```
^(?!(\d)\1+$)(?:\(?\+\d{1,3}\)?[- ]?|0)?\d{10}$
```

**[Demo for this updated regex](https://regex101.com/r/E9SCcu/2)**

Another way for validating mobile numbers can be, you replace everything that is not a digit and also get rid of all leading zeroes in your number, then what remains will be pure mobile number which you can further validate. But there may be certain disadvantages there as it may become a bit hard to figure out the country code and if the number is really valid. Because certain numbers may be less than ten digits and may actually be invalid but they may be valid if they belong to a country like Singapore which has I guess 8 digit numbers. And same with countries having eleven digits local number might trouble you.

Comment: Pleased to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is looking correct don't know why it is rejecting, can you try once with

```
^(\+[\d]{1,5}|0)?[7-9]\d{9}$
```

Maybe it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}$
```

This is work for me.